# Creating Action with codecept build in Codeception

Tags: testing, config, functional-testing, codeception

I make my first steps in creating functional tests with codeception.

This is my functional.suite.yml

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost'
- \Helper\Functional
```

Now I want to generate the actions for the FunctionalTester. I use this command:

```
vendor/bin/codecept build
```

No methods are added. I expected that methods like amOnUrl($url) are created in the trait FunctionalTesterActions. But this is my result.

```
Building Actor classes for suites: unit, acceptance, functional
 -> UnitTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\UnitTester includes modules: Asserts, \Helper\Unit
 -> AcceptanceTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\AcceptanceTester includes modules: PhpBrowser, \Helper\Acceptance
 -> FunctionalTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\FunctionalTester includes modules: \Helper\Functional, REST, PhpBrowser
```

The configuration should be OK. I tested this with the command

```
vendor/bin/codecept config:validate
```

What is my mistake? Thanks for every hint.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out I had a syntax error in my Helper.

Hope this helps someone in the future.